# Query with servicestack property display name

Tags: servicestack

I have some issue regarding display name of property in result of get request on servicestack.
I will get following result when i make get request to my servicestack, in that in list i have not bind **count** although it is displaying here (I think because of type (int)).

[image: ss2]

So my questions are

1) Is there any way to avoid property to displaying on Result? (want to disable count here)

2) Is there any way to rename property display name ? (want to display countvalue instead of count here)?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of **0** for count is displayed because that's what value is embedded in the JSON. If you don't want it displayed then you want to suppress the value from being serialized. If you make **count** property nullable (i.e. change from int to int?) then it wont be displayed when it doesn't have a value.

At the moment there is no way to customize the header label of each column other than changing the name of your DTO property to **CountValue**.

Comment: Hey great it's worked when i have changed to int? from int.. excellent!

Comment: One more issue is that i have taken count as property in perfmon class when i pass count in caps (?COUNT=2) then it will be null in request.count , is there any solution for that?

Comment: At the moment the properties in serialization are case-sensitive. Although you can parse the QueryString manually in your service with: `base.RequestContext.Get<IHttpRequest>().QueryString["COUNT"]`